# Applications Menu entry to start a local server in a Terminal and keep the terminal open for input

Tags: server, bash, minecraft

I would like to achieve the following:

By clicking on an Applications Menu entry, start a Minecraft server, which for the moment is running on my Ubuntu machine, keeping the Terminal window open (as a Console). I can then manage the server from that 'Console Window' when I return to the 'screen'.

I have tried this script from a .sh file on my desktop until I get it working:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen
cd /media/terabyte/minecraft/
./start.sh
```

But the terminal closes and the server is left running but I cannot control it and must kill it from the task manager.

Comment: Sure the server is left running? I expect that the script like you presented it drops you to a terminal prompt provided by screen. When you detach that session or end that session, the server is started and the script ends.

Answer (score 0):

To run the minecraft server in a screen session and keep that open when the minecraft server is terminated, change your script into:

```
#/bin/bash
screen -m bash -c 'cd /media/terabyte/minecraft/ && ./start.sh ; bash'
```

This will run screen, and within the screen session run the commands to start the server. Once the server is started, `bash` is called to keep a terminal open. Otherwise, the screen session would end.

To immediately move this screensession to the background, include the `-d` (detach) option. Then, you will need to attach to that screen session first in order to see your bash prompt belonging to that session.